# How to Unlock TFS Project Files?

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer

I Migrated my TFS(MyTFSServer) server to another TFS server(MyNewTFSServer). In this migration I have restored database from the old to the new server and some of the files awere  locked in old server workspace. In migration  from TFS2010 to TFS2012 with checked out files the status of each pending file migrates along with the source code

So now How I can unlock that files in my new sever. The old server is deleted. And when I am trying to checkout the file its saying that another user have checked out this file.  The following error occurs:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
Unable to perform operation on $/myproject/code/myfile.cs. The item $/myproject/code/myfile.cs is locked in workspace Dalvir-PC;dsing.
No files checked in.
```

But this file was checked out in old TFS server(MyTFSServer) and now I having the new User on New TFS(MyNewTFSServer) with the name "dalvir".
I am unable to checkout and checkin the file.

Please help me get rid of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if they were checked out in the old server or in the new one. For such administrative task I use TFS Sidekicks http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2012, which is for free use. You need admin rights to do task like undoing checkouts for other users. In Sidekicks use the Status Sidekick and search for the checkouts you want to undo.

Another option would be tf.exe using the undo command:

```
tf undo [/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
    [/recursive] itemspec [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
    [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```